# Is every human's soul reaped?

Tags: dead-like-me

In Dead Like Me, does every human have a soul?

Is everyone's soul reaped?

Or only a small subset, which is what we directly observe in the series episodes judging by the # of reapers and their workload?

Comment: There's mention of a reaper of plagues, presumably they do more in one go?

Comment: Remember, the reapers we see are in "Special Circumstances" meaning they by definition only handle the more bizarre and less common deaths, which accounts for their seemingly small workload. But since we have seen reapers even for animal souls, I think it's a safe bet that all souls are reaped by *someone*.

Comment: @Roger, the main characters are in the Outside Influences department. We also see members of the Plague department, as well as the two pet reapers.

Comment: @BrianS Thanks for the correction. Point still stands, though. They by definition don't cover things like natural causes, homicide, suicide, etc. which would all presumably be reaped by someone in a different department.

Comment: @Roger - That still doesn't answer the question of whether all humans have a soul or just a select few.

Comment: @Richard I would think that question might better belong on philosophy.SE ;-)

Comment: @Roger - Within the Dead Like Me-verse, obviously :-)

Answer (score 1):

All signs point to every *soul* being reaped, at least based on the various divisions (covering almost every conceivable way to die).

What isn't immediately clear is whether *every* human has a soul, but it's notable that when Roxy accosts a *random guy in the street* (in [Sunday Mornings](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0556092/?ref_=tt_ch)), he has a soul to "pop".

---

In addition to the '**external influences**' division, of which Georgia [becomes a member](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0556085/?ref_=ttep_ep1) ("*murders, suicides, accidents, etc. And I do mean etc*"), we learn that there are at least three other 'divisions' directly mentioned:

**Plague Division** (currently under-unoccupied)

> **PD Member:** *Come on. We’re Plague Division. All we’ve got is time.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Business Unfinished](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0556073/)</sup></sub>

**Natural Causes (evidently including old age)**

> **Penny:** *Natural causes is one of the nicer assignments for a reaper, especially in a hospital. No chasing anyone down. Everyone's got a name tag.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Forget Me Not](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0556077/?ref_=ttep_ep12)</sup></sub>

**Circulatory Disease**

> **Mason:** *Friends of mine at Circulatory Disease give me the skinny on vacancies in their division...*
>
> <sub><sup>[Dead Like Me: Pilot](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0556085/?ref_=ttep_ep1)</sup></sub>

Georgia also mentions three leading causes of death in relation to her work in External Circumstances. Since one of these is confirmed to be a division, it's plausible that all three are. Assuming that to be the case, the divisions mentioned cover more than 98% of all deaths.

> And death was everywhere. **Infectious and parasitic disease**, **Circulatory system disease**. **Malignant neoplasms**. Those were the big three. The leading causes of death worldwide. But they weren't my problem. Grim reapers are assigned to specific divisions. My division is External Influence.
>
> <sub><sup>[Dead Like Me: Pilot](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0556085/?ref_=ttep_ep1)</sup></sub>